# How can I store some float values in a for loop using vector in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv

i have some float values coming in a for loop .Now i want to store these values in a vector for further processing.how can i write in opencv 2.4.9. This is the code

```
for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++)
{
boundry.x= contours[i][j].x;
     boundry.y=contours[i][j].y ;
     float distx = x_comp-boundry.x;
    float disty = y_comp-boundry.y;
    float dist=sqrt((distx*distx)+(disty*disty));
}
}
```

Now i have to store these dist values in a vector for further processing. Please help

Comment: What is your question about this task?  Do you have a vector yet?

Comment: no. The dist values are coming in each loop. Now i have to store them

Comment: std::vector<double> distance;
  distance.push_back(dist); it is not working

Comment: do you create the std:vector outside the for loops?

Comment: Yes inside the loop.but when I print the values only single value is relatively coming

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the values for further processing you should have your vector defined outside of the for loops otherwise the data is not going to be saved. Then you can use a simple standard vector and push_back.

```
std::vector<float> distance;
for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
 for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++)
 {
    boundry.x= contours[i][j].x;
    boundry.y= contours[i][j].y ;
    float distx = x_comp-boundry.x;
    float disty = y_comp-boundry.y;
    float dist=sqrt((distx*distx)+(disty*disty));
    distance.push_back(dist);
 }
}
```

Comment: It is ok. But when I printf the values of distance vector only 0.00000 are coming. If  I change the vector<double> distance then a value like 5074432 repeated ly coming.so how can I display all the dist values in the vector

Comment: Have you compared the value printed inside and outside of the loop? What exact function do you use to print?

Comment: What is the type of you variable _contours_? Is it just an array or a cv::Mat?

Comment: The dist is calculated from cvpoint.it is the distances between a fixed point and array of points.Now I have to store these dist values in a vector for next processing

Comment: Contour is taken from cvcontour from opencv

Comment: But have you compared if you print inside the loop, directly with _dist_ or outside of the loop with the vector. To know if the problem is from the vector or not.

Comment: dist values are coming in side the for loop but i have to store them in a vector or single col mat

Comment: I know what is your goal. I´m asking you to do a small check to define from where your bug is coming. As the problem now is in the printing.